# Container background wont show

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the background to display for `body div.grid-container`.

**CSS:**

```css
body div.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1630px;
    height: auto;

    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

    background: #d4e7ed; background-color: #d4e7ed;
}
```

I've tried using `display: block;` for all the elements.
Still wont work.

Could you please **[Take a look here!](http://test.ample.pw/tta/landing/)**.

**The page is under construction, and it's still not responsive. So if your screen size is smaller than 1630px in width. Open it in Chrome and zoom out, using "Control" and "-".**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set:

```css
overflow: auto;
```

to your div.

This is because the parent div contains elements that float. When elements float, they don't force the height of the parent to expand.

Answer (score 2):

Use overflow and it will work :)

```css
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the blocks contained in your grid-container float to the left. They then don't force their container's height to adjust. You need to add a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) to your container.

Comment: Yuck. That clearfix solution contains a star hack. Not to mention it's 4 lines of code, 17 un-minified, compared to 1, and doesn't even address the real problem which is overflow.

Comment: I use the clearfix, as it allows for positionned elements outside, but I admit it might be overkill in many cases. And since I use a css preprocessor, I don't mind much the "ugliness" of the hack.